# How to bundle files such as images in a war files so that they will be accessble to Servlet?

Tags: java, android, file, tomcat, servlets

I have a folder like this:

```
File file=new File("/Users/mac/Desktop/h/"+device_id+"/"+postID+".jpg");
```

It works fine the above code.
But I When I place the folder /h INSIDE THE project and access the file via

```
File file=new File("/h/"+device_id+"/"+postID+".jpg");
```

It gives me file not found exception 
Anyone knoew how to properly implementing file access with a war file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try.

```
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getSession().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("<<Relative path from webroot of your project>>")));   E.g. Path value can be /WEB-INF/images/img1.jpg
```

The buffered reader will have the file content

or

```
InputStream is = request.getSession().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream( "<<Relative path from webroot of your project>>" );
```

You can get the contents from inputStream

Comment: I don't use sessions does it matter?

Comment: Good question. The ServletContext can get obtained in different ways. As you are already inside a Servlet you can get it using getServletContext(); which is a base class method E.g. @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    // ...
}     This is only if you don't want to get it via Session